# Garbage value in pointer to char

Tags: c++, pointers, char

In the code:

```
int main(){
int a = 10;
int * s =  &a;
cout << s;
}
```

The memory address of "a" gets printed as expected. However, when I try:

```
int main(){
char a = 10;
char * s =  &a;
cout << s;
}
```

The output is a garbage value. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The first fragment calls `operator<<(void*)` which prints the address. The second calls `operator<<(const char*)` which attempts to interpret the argument as a pointer to a NUL-terminated string, and print that string. If you want the address, make it `cout << static_cast<void*>(s);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - go ahead and write that up. Clear concise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `operator<<` has special functionality for handling character pointers since they are strings in legacy C. So it will assume that any `char *` you give it is a pointer to the first character in a legacy C string, and print it as such.

If you want to specifically treat it as a pointer, cast it to a pointer type *without* the special handling, something like:

```
cout << static_cast<void *>(s);
```